# How to easily consume a Kotlin channel producer in Java?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-interop, kotlinx.coroutines

As part of working on the development of a new API, I am learning to use Kotlin. Initially I want the Kotlin API to be used within a Java (Android) project, but in the long term I hope to adopt Kotlin entirely.

As part of improving the implementation of a long-running process, I want to use coroutines. Specifically, a [channel producer](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#building-channel-producers) from the `kotlinx.coroutines` package.

For example:

```
fun exampleProducer() = produce {
    send("Hello")
    delay(1000)
    send("World")
}
```

What is the best way to consume this in Java? I am okay with adding temporary 'helper' functions to Kotlin and/or Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to interop channels with Java is via Reactive Streams. Both Rx and Project Reactor are supported out-of-the-box. For example, add `kotlinx-coroutines-rx2` to your dependicies and you'll be able to use `rxFlowable` builder:

```
fun exampleFlowable() = rxFlowable<String> {
    send("Hello")
    delay(1000)
    send("World")
}
```

This function returns an instance of `Flowable`, which is specifically designed for ease-of-use from Java, for example, you can do in Java:

```
exampleFlowable().subscribe(t -> System.out.print(t));
```

Comment: Works perfectly, although I opted to use `rxObservable` in my case (I do not expect backpressure).

Answer (score 1):

Currently, assuming Java 8 is used and lambdas are available, I rely on a helper function defined in Kotlin which allows passing a callback to consume incoming results.

The helper method in Kotlin:

```
fun exampleProducerCallback( callback: (String) -> Unit ) = runBlocking {
    exampleProducer().consumeEach { callback( it ) }
}
```

This is then consumed in Java as:

```
ApiKt.exampleProducerCallback( text -> {
    System.out.print( text );
    return Unit.INSTANCE; // Needed since there is no void in Kotlin.
} );
```

Explanation on why `return Unit.INSTANCE` is needed [can be found in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37834971/590790).

Comment: I am totally new to Kotlin and have no idea whether or not this is idiomatic. I merely posted my current solution to let you know where I am at right now. Perhaps there are better alternatives available?

Comment: An obvious improvement is using `callback: Consumer<String>` instead.