# How to pass function as parameter from java to kotlin method?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a Kotlin Code:

```
fun showAdWithCallback(callback:() -> Unit) {
    if (AdsPrefs.shouldShowInterstitialAd()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show()
        this.callback = callback
    } else {
        callback()
    }
}
```

Now I want to call this method from a Java Class. I am confused about how to call this. Here is what I tried

```
  showAdWithCallback(() -> {
        return null;
    });
```

But it shows following error.

[image]

Comment: how about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37828790/why-do-i-have-to-return-unit-instance-when-implementing-in-java-a-kotlin-functio

Comment: Check out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120697/kotlin-how-to-pass-a-function-as-parameter-to-another

Comment: @P.Juni The reference you gave has a callback that accept one argument, but I have a callback without any parameters. So that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @VipulPrajapati The reference you gave has examples of passing function from a kotlin code to kotlin functions, what I want here is to let my java class use function in kotlin class (which accepts function as a argument)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685563/how-to-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-java

Comment: @PrajeetShrestha please share the code before your `showAdWithCallback`

Comment: @BartekLipinski. Oh u got me........I had return statement just before showAdWithCallback. I was randomly embedding showAdWithCallback to tryout, overlooked the return statement. Thank u so much. You can put it as a answer I will accept and upvote.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error message is caused by **the code before** your:

```
showAdWithCallback(() -> {
        return null;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Call kotlin object and call function

```
kotlinobject.INSTANCE.showAdWithCallback(()->{
    return null;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

callback:() -> Unit

It's a typically runnable - zero arguments, without return value