# Calling asynchronous kotlin method from java

Tags: java, asynchronous, kotlin

I have a library written in kotlin which i want to use in my Java program, but i don't know how to call an asynchronous method correctly.

```
/*This is my asynchronous kotlin method from the library*/

fun getNames(callback: (List<String>) -> Unit) = ...

/*In Java i want to call this method*/

List<String> names = getNames(...);
```

What parameter do i have to pass into the function in Java?
IntelliJ says i need something like this: `'kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1<? super java.util.List<String>,kotlin.Unit>'` But i don't know how to instantiate such a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first of all give it a look at [this great response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37834971/11984305) from [Kirill Rakhman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615306/kirill-rakhman).

Now, the result given by a callback from a asynchronous operation will come from the parameter. In this case it'll be the `(List<String>)` at the `fun getNames()`.

A simple usage of this function in JAVA (8+) can look like this :

```
getNames(
    strings -> {
        strings.forEach(System.out::println);
        return Unit.INSTANCE;
    }
);
```

Comment: and if the kotlin function does return something, how can i access this return by using the "FunctionalUtils" helper method from @KirillRakhman?