# Kotlin method in java

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to write the code below written in Kotlin, in Java. I am not able to create the DefaultElementsAdapter as I am unable to get the syntax right.

```
HtmlRecycler.Builder(this@MainActivity)  
    .setSource(networkSource)  
    .setAdapter(DefaultElementsAdapter(this@MainActivity) { element, i, view ->  
    }})
    .setRecyclerView(recyclerView)  
    .setLoadingCallback(object : HtmlRecycler.LoadCallback {  
        override fun onLoadingStart() {  
            progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE  
        }  
        override fun onLoaded(document: Document?) {  
            progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
    }  
    })  
    .build()
```

I am unable to get this right Java Code

```
    DefaultElementsAdapter adapter = new DefaultElementsAdapter(this, 

 /****How to create the kotlin adapter here****/


    );

            HtmlRecycler.Builder builder = new HtmlRecycler.Builder(this);
            builder.setSource(new StringSource(item.contentDescription))
                    .setRecyclerView(recyclerView)
                    .setAdapter(adapter)
            .build();
```

The Kotlin class is something like this

```
public final class DefaultElementsAdapter public constructor(context: android.content.Context, onClick: (m7mdra.com.htmlrecycler.elements.Element, kotlin.Int, android.view.View) -> kotlin.Unit) : m7mdra.com.htmlrecycler.adapter.ElementsAdapter {
    private final val context: android.content.Context /* compiled code */

    private final val onClick: (m7mdra.com.htmlrecycler.elements.Element, kotlin.Int, android.view.View) -> kotlin.Unit /* compiled code */

    public open fun onBindElement(holder: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: kotlin.Int): kotlin.Unit { /* compiled code */ }

    public open fun onCreateElement(parent: android.view.ViewGroup, elementType: m7mdra.com.htmlrecycler.elements.ElementType): androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

I am trying to use the library https://github.com/m7mdra/HtmlRecycler

Comment: Sry did not get it, what is the problem? What is the error?

Comment: @barotia I am trying to write the code written in Kotlin in Java. I am not able to create the DefaultElementsAdapter as I am unable to get the syntax right.

Comment: I don't understand why the negative rating

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DefaultElementAdapter` constructor expects its second argument to be a function of type `(Element, Int, View) -> Unit`, which means that it has to accept 3 arguments, `Element`, `Int` (`int` or `Integer` in Java) and `View`, and doesn't return anything.

If you have [enabled Java 8 support in your Android project](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support), you can provide the needed function using a lambda expression:

```
DefaultElementsAdapter adapter = new DefaultElementsAdapter(this, (element, i, view) -> {
    // your code
    return Unit.INSTANCE;
});
```

If you don't have Java 8 support and can't use lambdas, you can always create a `Function3` object:

```
DefaultElementsAdapter adapter = new DefaultElementsAdapter(this, new Function3<Element, Integer, View, Unit>() {
    @Override
    public Unit invoke(Element element, Integer integer, View view) {
        // your code
        return Unit.INSTANCE;
    }
});
```

Note that unfortunately you have to return `Unit.INSTANCE` in Java in both cases. The reason behind such need has been already explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37834971/11342519).